# Is it possible to have a Struts2 application without using any suffixes like action or do?

Tags: java, url, struts2

By default, Struts 2 uses the suffix `.action` to represent action URLs. So, even if I want to get to a login page, I need to use a URL something like : `http://mysite.com/login.action`.

But I feel the above URL is not flexible and not SEO friendly. So, is there any way to avoid the `.action` suffix or any suffixes completely and just use plain URLs (eg: `http://mysite.com/login`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible,  you can use something like this `<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="htm">` in struts.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have tested that add the below codes in your `struts.xml` file, If you want to remove any suffix from URL, you can do this:

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=",">
```